# JSTree Exclude different nodes from selection

Tags: javascript, jstree

In my project I have 3 company root nodes and test children.With Checkboxes.

```
- []Company1
-- []Test1
-- []Test2
- []Company2
-- []Test1
-- []Test2
-- []Test 3
- []Company3
-- []Test1
```

The tree is much more complex, but for question I reduced the levels. However, I want to manage, that it is forbidden to select two  Companies. As sample, if Test1 from Company2 is selected and the user select Test1 from Company1, then all selections from Company1 and Company3 get unchecked.

My code for the jstree is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#html1').on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data){
            var countSelected = data.selected.length;
            if (countSelected>1) {
                data.instance.deselect_node( [ data.selected[0] ] );
            }
        });
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/jstreecontent",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#html1').jstree({
                'core' : {
                    'data' : data
                },
                "checkbox" : {
                    "keep_selected_style" : false
                },
                "plugins" : [ "checkbox", "contextmenu"],
                "checkbox": {
                    three_state : true, // to avoid that fact that checking a node also check others
                    whole_node : false,  // to avoid checking the box just clicking the node
                    tie_selection : false // for checking without selecting and selecting without checking
                },
                "contextmenu": {
                    "items": function ($node) {
                        var tree = $("#html1").jstree(true);
                        if($node.a_attr.type === 'test')
                            return getTestContextMenu($node, tree);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This function will be triggered always, when ajax request is completed, even it fails/returns other status code
            console.log("complete");
        },
        error: function() {
            // This will be triggered when ajax request fail.
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });

});
```

If I remove the part:

```
                "checkbox": {
                    three_state : true, // to avoid that fact that checking a node also check others
                    whole_node : false,  // to avoid checking the box just clicking the node
                    tie_selection : false // for checking without selecting and selecting without checking
                },
```

The selection with the root nodes works perfect, just one root node is allowed, but I cannot select a whole root, just its nodes. So I think the

```
    $('#html1').on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data){
            var countSelected = data.selected.length;
            if (countSelected>1) {
                data.instance.deselect_node( [ data.selected[0] ] );
            }
        });
```

Is working on all nodes, not only on the top one. Maybe this is wrong.

But it seems, I fail with it, it is the wrong way. I hope someone else had the same problem in the past and give me a hint for this.

Comment: *"I fail with it"*: the code you provided does not do anything useful. I suppose you have some code inside that handler. Could you add it?

Comment: Make the company select-able with a radio button.

Comment: The conditions are bit confusing. Please give more information on when do you want the checkboxes on Company 1, 2 or 3 to be unchecked. If you can provide the code snippet it'll be easier to understand the issue.

Comment: Question was updated with more information and code.